# Using preg_match to check URL with "wildcard"

Tags: php, preg-match

So I want to check if a string is in the format:

*checkout/00/payment*

where 00 can be any number.

I tried using preg_match to do this, but it didn't work out:

```
if(preg_match('/checkout/ [0-9] /payment/', $url, $matches)){
         echo 'hello';  
}
```

Further I want it to fail if the string has any characters after the word 'payment'
e.g checkout/00/payment/more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex below now matches as you would expect. Notice that I surrounded the digits with parenthesis. This captures the number in $matches so you can use it later.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

foreach(array(0,5,10,99) as $i)
{
    $num = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $url = 'checkout/'.$num.'/payment';

    if(preg_match('/checkout\/([0-9]+)\/payment/i', $url, $matches))
    {
        echo 'url: "'.$url."\"\n";
        echo 'hello: '.$matches[1]."\n";
        print_r($matches);
    }

    echo "\n\n";
}
?>
```

This code produces the following output:

```
url: "checkout/00/payment"
hello: 00
Array
(
    [0] => checkout/00/payment
    [1] => 00
)


url: "checkout/05/payment"
hello: 05
Array
(
    [0] => checkout/05/payment
    [1] => 05
)


url: "checkout/10/payment"
hello: 10
Array
(
    [0] => checkout/10/payment
    [1] => 10
)


url: "checkout/99/payment"
hello: 99
Array
(
    [0] => checkout/99/payment
    [1] => 99
)
```

[preg_match manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

[preg_match_all manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

[PCRE regex syntax manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

[Possible modifiers in regex patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score 2):

`[0-9]` matches only a single digit. If you want to match exactly two digits, append `{2}`: `[0-9]{2}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has extra spaces in it, and `[0-9]` will only match one digit.

Also, if you start and end your regex with `/`, you can't use `/` inside it, unless you escape it with a backslash (`\/`).

I've used `~` instead for this.

```
if(preg_match('~checkout/([0-9]+)/payment$~', $url, $matches)) {
    echo 'Matched! (' . $matches[1] . ')';
}
```

This will match one or more digits.

Demo: [codepad.viper-7.com/qoKI5G](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qoKI5G)